# Visual Studio Code IDE auto propose function for custom functions

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, ide

I have created some custom functions and I have found that there is no auto suggested function screen prompt when I input 'the dot' syntax. Is there any config. I am missing?

[image]

Below is my file structure in package "ws_functions".

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using pylance which requires an `extraPaths` setting for intellisense to work properly in subdirectories (they really need to fix this).

Create a directory `.vscode` in the root of your project, then create a `settings.json` file in that folder. Edit the content of `settings.json` as follows:

[image]

```js
{
  "python.analysis.extraPaths": ["ws_functions"] // the name of your project folder dirctory
}
```

now you should be able to:

```
from . import config # or another file

# intellisense should show completions
config.
```

For more info see here: https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/blob/main/TROUBLESHOOTING.md#unresolved-import-warnings

Comment: Thanks. I think I need to reinstall Pylance as this issue only occurs in my local env.